# linaro/gcc-aarch64-none-elf/4.9-2015.03 issue with NEON

Tags: gcc, arm, neon, linaro

I'm compiling an ARM code that doesn't support the NEON, but I'm getting an exception, because one of the C-Library "printf" is trying to access a NEON register Q0 "str    q0, [x29,#112]".

I used a lot of options in order to prevent the compiler from calling NEON registers, but it seems that the issue is not obvious. I used : -march=armv8-a+nofp, -mgeneral-regs-only, -mcpu=cortex-a53+nofp...

Any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: Well, if the offending instructions are in a library, then you'll clearly need to either recompile _that library_ with appropriate settings, or find an alternative. Yes, even libc.